# display only the elements with checked = true

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, underscore.js, lodash

I have a list of items with the option to checked or unchecked.

```
  <ion-item ng-repeat="sport in sports"
            ng-click="toggleSportSelection(sport)">
    {{:: sport.name}}
  </ion-item>
```

if those items are unchecked you are unable to see them here

```
<div ng-show="sport.checked" ng-repeat="sport in sports">
      {{sport.name}}
</div>
```

those items has been saved in a DB every time you unchecked them.

The reason why I am here, is because the default behavior of the items is `checked = true` so it doesn't matter if they are saved in a DB, if you refresh the page, all the items are set up to `checked = true` again.

So what can I do in order to avoid that behavior and that the app recognizes once the items are unchecked or checked ?

this is part of the controller

```
.controller('SportsController', function($scope, SportsFactory,
                                                AuthFactory) {

  SportsFactory.getSportChecked(customer).then(function(sportChecked) {
    _.each(sports, function(sport) {
      var intersectedSports = _.intersection(sport.id, sportChecked),
          checkedSportObjects = _.filter(sport, function(sportObj) {
           return _.includes(intersectedSports, sportObj);
        });
         _.each(checkedSportObjects, function(sport) {
            $scope.sports.push(sport);
          });
         });

    //here is the part where the default behavior is checked = true

      if (sports.length) {
        $scope.sports = _.map(sports, function(sport) {
          sport.checked = true;
          return sport;
        });
      }

    $scope.toggleSportSelection = function(sport) {
      var params = {};
      params.user = $scope.customer.customer;
      params.sport = sport.id;
      sport.checked = !sport.checked;
      SportsFactory.setSportChecked(params);
    };
});
```

**UPDATE**

service.js

```
  setSportChecked: function(params) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    $http.post(CONSTANT_VARS.BACKEND_URL + '/sports/checked', params)
    .success(function(sportChecked) {
        LocalForageFactory.remove(CONSTANT_VARS.LOCALFORAGE_SPORTS_CHECKED, params);
        defer.resolve(sportChecked);
      })
      .error(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        defer.reject(err);
      });
    return defer.promise;
  },
```

**and the NODEJS part**

```
  sportChecked: function(params) {
    var Promise = require('bluebird');
    return new Promise(function(fullfill, reject) {
      console.time('sportChecked_findOne');
      SportSelection.findOne({
        user: params.user
      }).exec(function(err, sportChecked) {
        console.timeEnd('sportChecked_findOne');
        var newSport;
        if (err) {
          reject(new Error('Error finding user'));
          console.error(err);
        }else if (sportChecked) {
          newSport =  sportChecked.sport || [];
          console.log(newSport);
          console.time('sportChecked_update');
          if (_.includes(sportChecked.sport, params.sport)) {
            console.log('Sport already exists');
            console.log(sportChecked.sport);
            sportChecked.sport = _.pull(newSport, params.sport);
            // sportChecked.sport = _.difference(newSport, params.sport);
            console.log(sportChecked.sport);
          }else {
            newSport.push(params.sport);
            sportChecked.sport = newSport;
          }
          SportSelection.update({
            user: params.user
          },
          {
            sport: newSport
          }).exec(function(err, sportCheckedUpdated) {
            console.timeEnd('sportChecked_update');
            if (err) {
              reject(new Error('Error on sportChecked'));
            }else {
              fullfill(sportCheckedUpdated);
            }
          });
          if (sportChecked.sport) {
            sportChecked.sport.push(params.sport);
            console.log('New sport added');
          }else {
            sportChecked.sport = [params.sport];
          }
        }else {
          console.time('sportChecked_create');
          SportSelection.create({
            sport: [params.sport],
            user: params.user
          }).exec(function(err, created) {
              console.timeEnd('sportChecked_create');
              if (err) {
                reject(new Error('Error on sportChecked'));
              }else {
                fullfill(created);
              }
            });
        }
      });
    });
  },
```

I am using `lodash` so I will appreciate if you can assist me with that.

My issue itself is: it doesn't matter if the items are unchecked, once you refresh the page, all the items will be set up to checked = true again.

Someone says that I can use `_.difference`, but how ? or what can I do? I am here to read your suggestions.

Comment: Does `setSportChecked` cause the `checked` parameter in the database to toggle? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
.controller('SportsController', function($scope, SportsFactory) {
  // get a list of all sports, with default value false
  SportsFactory.getAllSports().then(function(sports){
    $scope.sports = sports;
    // set all items to unchecked
    angular.each($scope.sports, function(sport) {
      sport.checked = false;
    });

    // get a list of checked sports for customer
    SportsFactory.getCheckedSports(customer).then(function(checkedSports) 
    {
      // set the sports in your list as checked
      angular.each(checkedSports, function(checkedSport){
        var sport = _.findWhere($scope.sports, {id: checkedSport.id});
        sport.checked = true;
    });

  });

  $scope.toggleSportSelection = function(sport) {
    // do your toggle magic here
  };
});
```

In your view use a filter:

```
<div ng-repeat="sport in sports | filter:{checked:true}">
{{sport.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: what do you think I have to do with the toggle magic? it is not right what I did first ? ```$scope.toggleSportSelection = function(sport) { sport.checked = !sport.checked; };```

Comment: and actually I guess that if I do what you said, once I refresh the page all the items set to ```checked=false``` will be ```checked=true``` again

Comment: I don't there's much wrong with the toggle part, that's why I didn't include it. At your `if (sports.length)` you set all sports to checked, ignoring what the server result is. Also, check if the toggleSport method is outside of the then() callback function.

Comment: so can you help me a bit fixing my code ? sorry I am a novice

Comment: Well try my suggestion - also check the updated anwer, I set all items to unchecked except the checked result from the database.